# Show that tanz doesn't assume i, -i

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

This question is from my assignment in complex analysis and I was unable to solve it.

> Prove that tanz doesn't assume the value i, -i. Does this contradict Picard's Theorem.

Attempt- tanz = $ i \frac{e^{iz} -e^{-iz}} { e^{iz}+ e^{-iz}}$  => $e^{iz}=i$ and z=π/2 and z=-π/2 is not in domain. But how does it tells which values will never be attained?  So, how to deduce it?

I think picard theorem is not violated as tanz is not entire, due to cosz being in denominator.

Am I right?

Comment: Hint: $e^{iz} \ne 0 \; \forall z \in \Bbb{C}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you want to say that $$\tan z=i\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+ e^{-iz}}=\pm i \,,$$ which becomes equivalent to $$e^{\pm iz}=0\,,$$ which is impossible (the exponential function has no complex zeroes).